# PHP while Loop with Inner Loop

Tags: php

Im hoping someone can help me with a small problem!

I have a php while loop that loops 3 times.

Each time it loops I want an inner loop to output 2 incremental values per loop.

For example:

```
Loops the first time: Inner loop should output value 1, value 2

Loops the second time: Inner loop should output value 3, value 4

Loops the third time: Inner loop should output value 5, value 6
```

any ideas?

Comment: so you write the two loops.. what's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this :

```
$in = 1;
$out = 0;
while (++$out <= 3) {
    echo "Outer loop $out : ";
    for ($i=0 ; $i<2 ; $i++) {
        echo "$in ";
        $in++;
    }
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Which gets me the following output :

```
Outer loop 1 : 1 2
Outer loop 2 : 3 4
Outer loop 3 : 5 6
```

Basically, here :

- I'm using the `$out` variable to keep track of the number of times I've been through the outer loop -- I only want to loop 3 times
- I'm using the `$i` variable to control how many times the inner loop loops -- two times, each time the outer while loops.
- And I'm using the `$in` variable as a **global counter**, incremented by 1 every time the inner loop loops -- this is what I want to output.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be very useful in case this was some project problem, but here's a solution that only requires one loop.

```
for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++) {
  echo "Outer loop $i : ".($i*2-1)." ".($i*2);
}
```

This is possible only because of the relation between the printed numbers. There exists a linear dependency between the tuples `(1,2,3)`, `(1,3,5)` and `(2,4,6)`.